# Regex for cookie matching

Tags: javascript, regex, cookies

I am still in the process of learning reg-ex and I came across a piece of code in which I am unable to understand the reg-ex properly.

```
  if (getCookie('hulk_token')) {
    localStorage.hulk = getCookie('hulk_token')
  }

  if (getCookie('user_name')) {
    localStorage.user = getCookie('user_name')
  }


  let getCookie = (name) => {
    var match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + name + '=([^;]+)'))
    if (match) {
      return match[2]
    }
    return null
  }
```

Okay, so above works perfectly well.
Now, I want to call the `getCookie` function using `token` and `name` values instead of `hulk_token` and `user_name` as is there right now.

I simply changed the values but it returns NULL. I am assuming there is something in reg-ex as well that I have to change but I cannot really wrap my head around this.

Clarification:

Values that I get in cookie are like this:

`hulk_token=abc23-12343-12243-24343`

`user_name=jdoe`

Updated values would be like this:

`token=abc23-12343-12243-24343`

`name=jdoe`

So, just the keys in cookie have changed.

Comment: Can you provide the sample of some name and token value that you're passing? You can also visit [Regex playground](https://regex101.com/r/rFL9Q4/1) and see yourself

Comment: @Mandy8055 added clarification in original question

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the regEx is built correctly, you might have problem with cookies itself. Check please if you really have the cookies name and token set in the document.

Comment: how can I check this out if the above regex is working properly?

Comment: on the page where you run this script open console in browser, and execute document.cookie and copy the output. Go to any online regex matcher i.e. https://regex101.com/ and insert as a regex "(^| )hulk_token=([^;]+)" and in the text field insert the content from document.cookie that you have already copied.

but thats an overkill, I have checked your function it works properly, check your cookies, if you want to take the cooke by name that doesnt exist in cookies then you will get null as result.